# Singledispatch based on value instead of type

Tags: python, django

I building SPA on Django and I have one huge function with many `if` statement for checking state name of my object field. Like this:

```
if self.state == 'new':
    do some logic
if self.state == 'archive':
    do some logic
```

and so on. I reading nice book "Fluent python" now, and I mention about `@singledispatch` decorator, it looks so great, but it can overide function only with diferent type of parametres like `str`, `int`, etc.
Question is, if there in python or Django way to separate logic like in my huge function with overided function like `singledispatch` do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is, though you have to write it. One possibility is to create a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) that does the dispatching based on `instance.state` or any chosen `state_attr`:

```
class StateDispatcher(object):

    def __init__(self, state_attr='state'):
        self.registry = {}
        self._state_attr = state_attr

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self

        method = self.registry[getattr(instance, self._state_attr)]
        return method.__get__(instance, owner)

    def register(self, state):
        def decorator(method):
            self.registry[state] = method
            return method

        return decorator
```

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods:

> To support method calls, functions include the `__get__()` method for binding methods during attribute access. This means that all functions are non-data descriptors which return bound or unbound methods depending whether they are invoked from an object or a class.

In your stateful class you can then create a dispatcher and register methods:

```
class StateMachine(object):

    dispatcher = StateDispatcher()
    state = None

    @dispatcher.register('test')
    def test(self):
        print('Hello, World!', self.state)

    @dispatcher.register('working')
    def do_work(self):
        print('Working hard, or hardly working?', self.state)
```

Let's see it in action:

```
>>> sm = StateMachine()
>>> sm.state = 'test'
>>> sm.dispatcher()
Hello, World! test
>>> sm.state = 'working'
>>> sm.dispatcher()
Working hard, or hardly working? working
>>> sm.state = None
>>> sm.dispatcher()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "dispatcher.py", line 11, in __get__
    method = self.registry[getattr(instance, self._state_attr)]
KeyError: None
```

Note that this is a quite evil method of dispatching based on state, since for future readers of your code the whole mechanism will be hard to follow.

Another method of dispatching on textual state is to encode the state in your method names and choose the correct method based on that in a dispatching function. Many python classes use this pattern ([`ast.NodeVisitor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor) for example):

```
class StateMachine(object):

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwgs):
        getattr(self, 'do_{}'.format(self.state))(*args, **kwgs)

    def do_new(self):
        print('new')

    def do_archive(self):
        print('archive')


sm = StateMachine()
sm.state = 'new'
sm.dispatch()
sm.state = 'archive'
sm.dispatch()
```

Comment: Thank a lot for intresting answer. I realy have to learn this `descriptor` magic

Answer (score 3):

Another way, if you want to use single dispatch, is to define state classes for states. You can make them "as string-like as possible". E.g. something like:

```py
from functools import singledispatch

class State:
    @classmethod
    def make_state(cls, state_name: str) -> 'State':
        state = type(state_name, (State,), {})
        setattr(cls, state_name, state)
        return state()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__


state_a = State.make_state("a")
state_b = State.make_state("b")

@singledispatch
def foo(s: State) -> str:
    raise NotImplementedError("Used dispatched")

@foo.register
def foo_a(s: State.a):
    return 'a'

@foo.register
def foo_b(s: State.b):
    return 'b'

print(foo(state_a))
print(foo(state_b))
# prints:
# a
# b
```