# Overloading and strategy pattern

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, overloading, strategy-pattern

I'm trying to write an email delivery system. I have this enum, for all users, users that were logged in the last 3 months and 6 months:

```
class Receiver(enum.Enum):
    ALL = "ALL"
    THREE_MONTHS = "THREE_MONTHS"
    SIX_MONTHS = "SIX_MONTHS"
```

The problem is, I'm trying to implement a **Strategy pattern**, so I need to *enforce type checking*. I know it is impossible by default, but ... any idea would be appreciated.

I need it to look like:

```
def send_to(Receiver.ALL):
    pass

def send_to(Receiver.THREE_MONTHS):
    pass

def send_to(Receiver.SIX_MONTHS):
    pass
```

Yeah, I have **Java background**.

And the general sender would pass the value **accordingly**:

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def send_email(request):
        email_to = request.data["emailTo"]
        send_to(email_to)
```

Note: I **do not want** to write multiple if checks or switch cases. It totally contradicts with Open Closed principle of Uncle Bob, since if there is gonna be additional case, then the method must be modified. Absolutely unacceptable.

Comment: You probably need `functools.singledispatch`, but overloading on literal values. Thus [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36836161/singledispatch-based-on-value-instead-of-type)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Singledispatch based on value instead of type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36836161/singledispatch-based-on-value-instead-of-type)

Comment: @SUTerliakov `singledispatch` is type-based, not value-based, so you would still need to map values of `email_to` to appropriately typed values.

Comment: Have you read the question I linked (or its question at least)? It is exactly about "singledispatch" alternative for value-based resolution...

Comment: I posted that comment before (or at the same time) you proposed the duplicate. I was responding to your comment about `functools.singledispatch` specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't have function overloading. What it *does* have is first-class function objects.

Create a `dict` that maps `Receiver` values to the appropriate function.

```
def send_to_all():
    pass

def send_to_last_three_months():
    pass

def send_to_last_six_months():
    pass

senders = {
    Receiver.ALL: send_to_all,
    Receiver.THREE_MONTHS: send_to_last_three_months,
    Receiver.SIX_MONTHS: send_to_last_six_months,
}

@api_view(["POST"])
def send_email(request):
    email_to = request.data["emailTo"]
    sender = senders[email_to]
    sender()
```

Comment: It throws KeyError :/

Comment: I did something like this:             receiver = Receiver[email_to]
                                                    send = receivers[receiver]
                                                    send(subject=subject, message=message)

Comment: But now I'm getting Assertion error on  send(subject=subject, message=message)

Comment: Forgot return keyword ))). Thanks, this will do the trick.